# Passing arguments using IfValueT

Tags: document-classes, xparse

I have seen the following usage:

```
\NewTColorBox[]{containerbox}{o o}{
    %invisible boxes for sections (now grey)
    boxsep=0cm,
    boxrule=0cm,
    sharp corners,
    left=0cm,
    right=0cm,
    top=0cm,
    bottom=0cm,
    leftright skip=0cm,
    nobeforeafter,
    IfValueT={#1}{width=#1},
    IfValueT={#2}{equal height group=#2},
}
```

I want to understand how the last two lines before the ending `}` work. I have seen how `IfValueT` works as a conditional statement, as in `IfValueT{condition}{code_if_condition_met}{code_if_condition_unmet}`. But the usage

```
IfValueT = {#1}{width=#1}
```

seems strange because it feels like the `\NewTColorBox` should recognize `IfValueT` as an argument... yet it somehow doesn't??

It seems like the way it's used is that *if* the first optional parameter to `containerbox` will be passed, then the width parameter gets passed to `\NewTColorBox` when creating an instance of `containerbox`, and if not, then the width parameter is not passed to `\NewTColorBox`. Am I getting this right? And if so, how does it work? Is the compiler simply treating the `IfValueT` as an argument in a special way? And would something like

```
\NewTColorBox[]{containerbox}{o}{
IfValueT = {#1}{width=#1}{width=1.0}
}
```

also work if I want to have a width of 1 in case no optional parameter gets passed?

What about the usage

```
\NewTColorBox[]{containerbox}{o}{
left=0cm,
IfValueT{#1}{width=#1}{width=1.0}
}
```

Would this work and be equivalent to what I had before?

Comment: that is key from the tcolorbox package, so check its (quite good and complete) documentation about how to use the key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `IfValueT` key is defined as a key taking three arguments, the definition looks like this (from `tcolorbox.sty` -- line numbering added by me):

```
875   \ExplSyntaxOn
876   \tcbset
877     {
...   
888       IfValueT/.code~n~args={2}{\tl_if_novalue:nF{#1}{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}},
...   
893     }
894   \ExplSyntaxOff
```

So what the key does is take two arguments after the equals sign, then it checks whether the first argument is the special no-value marker (which is the default value for an `o` type argument), and if it isn't it uses `\pgfkeysalso{#2}` which will set additional keys. So `IfValueT` is just a simple key that executes some useful code.

Another such useful key is `IfValueTF` which allows what you're asking for, namely setting different keys if the value was given or not:

```
\NewTColorBox[]{containerbox}{o}
  {
    left=0cm,
    IfValueTF={#1}{width={#1}}{width=1.0}
  }
```

But in the case that you just want to use a default value for `width` and always use it (in which case the behaviour is different from omitting the `width` key with the `IfValueT={#1}{width={#1}}` solution) it is much simpler to just set a default value for your optional `width` argument:

```
\NewTColorBox[]{containerbox}{O{1.0cm}}
  {
    left=0cm,
    width={#1}
  }
```

Example document using the suggested optional argument with a default value:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\NewTColorBox{containerbox}{O{1cm}}{left=0cm, width={#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{containerbox}
  some thin box
\end{containerbox}
\begin{containerbox}[5cm]
  some thick box
\end{containerbox}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]